System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.1.2.0 Exception in ASP.NET
After deploying new method, I stumbled upon this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

And I have tried referencing to this exact dll, but I'm getting this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)`

I have tried this answer here but it's not working as per my understanding in nuget website version 4.1.2.0 (nuget library) is not there.
I'm using .NET framework 4.6 and I have turned on debug to true in web.config as well.
Could anyone enlighten me about this error and how to fix?
